# Is there a way to place specsync.json file in some other folder

Tags: specflow

I tried to install specsync using the following commands
dotnet tool **install SpecSync.AzureDevOps** in a config folder, later in the same folder I had run **dotnet specsync init** , by this time when I build no error is coming, later when I install **SpecSync.AzureDevOps.SpecFlow.3-0** nugget and then build I got following error

```
#error SpecSync plugin error: Unable to load SpecSync configuration: The specified config file 'C:\kallki\YikeAutomation\Yike.Automation\specsync.json' does not exist. To create a new config file, use the 'init' command (e.g. 'dotnet specsync init' or 'SpecSync4AzureDevOps.exe init') or check the documentation at https://speclink.me/specsync-setup #line 1 "1PNonFundamentalEnergy.feature"#line hidden
```

So basically I want to place my specsync.json in some third party/config folder but I am not able to do so, is there any way I could do ?

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
dotnet specsync publish-test-results C:\Path\To\Your\specsync.json
```

as according to doc:

```
config-file-path (pos. 0)- (Default: [detect from current folder])
```

The path of the SpecSync for Azure DevOps configuration file, absolute path or relative to the current folder.

E.g.

```
'MyProject.Specs\specsync4tfs.json'.
```